# Can we use WSO2 DSS for using of Apache DRILL

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

In wso2 DSS we can create generic RDMS Engine can be used. So, can we use Apache Drill which has JDBC driver with WSO2 DSS.

When I used Drill it gave the following error.

```
DS Fault Message: Error creating JDBC Pool SQL Config: Error in creating external data source: org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms_4.4.9
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: test
Location: \test.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Nested Exception:-
org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error in creating external data source: org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms_4.4.9

        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.JDBCPoolSQLConfig.getDataSource(JDBCPoolSQLConfig.java:66)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.JDBCPoolSQLConfig.getDataSource(JDBCPoolSQLConfig.java:46)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.SQLConfig.createConnection(SQLConfig.java:180)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.SQLConfig.createConnection(SQLConfig.java:172)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.SQLConfig.initSQLDataSource(SQLConfig.java:150)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.RDBMSConfig.<init>(RDBMSConfig.java:43)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.ConfigFactory.getRDBMSConfig(ConfigFactory.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.ConfigFactory.createConfig(ConfigFactory.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceFactory.createDataService(DataServiceFactory.java:159)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.createDBService(DBDeployer.java:797)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.processService(DBDeployer.java:1152)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.deploy(DBDeployer.java:201)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error in creating external data source: org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms_4.4.9
        at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.utils.RDBMSDataSourceUtils.handleExternalDataSource(RDBMSDataSourceUtils.java:338)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.utils.RDBMSDataSourceUtils.createPoolConfiguration(RDBMSDataSourceUtils.java:290)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSource.<init>(RDBMSDataSource.java:55)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.JDBCPoolSQLConfig.getDataSource(JDBCPoolSQLConfig.java:62)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms_4.4.9
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.utils.RDBMSDataSourceUtils.handleExternalDataSource(RDBMSDataSourceUtils.java:333)
        ... 31 more
```

But I have used the correct jar only beacuase I'm able to connect using same jar in java code(JDBC).

Comment: where did you put the jar file?

Comment: repository/components/lib

Comment: start the server with -osgiConsole and once the server start check if the org.apache.drill.jdbc package get exported